# EF Core DbContext Create Table for Custom Data Models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to ***create database tables*** via instance of ***EntityFrameworkCore DbContext*** for ***custom data models*** which are *not added to `DbContext` as `DbSet`* property.

Is that possible?

***Update:***

I would like to create a library that takes context and works with its own data model. Client project doesn't need to know library's data models[Context class doesn't have to dbset properties for custom models].

For example, aspnet core Identity. Library project uses a few database tables as I try to do, but dbcontext should inherit from IdentityDbContext. Thanks to this inheritance, DbContext has DbSet properties.

If I use DbContext for custom data models, I don't need to extend DbContext class.

Comment: Maybe explain the purpose behind it? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It's possible to have entity w/o corresponding DbSet if that's what you are asking. See [Including & Excluding Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types).

Comment: you can run queries with ef , so any valid query command will work https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: In my case, context doesn't have Blogs DbSet. Blog model class exists in library project and context will come from consumer project. Context class doesn't know required class and model definitions. `context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); ` 
 if I doesn't add Blogs DbSet property, `context.Blogs` will not work.

Comment: I think you could make a context register "random" classes at runtime because in fact that's what it always does. But the classes should match a database schema, and they should be mappable by EF (contain the right collection types, have parameterless constructors etc. etc.), so the class library would require a lot of EF and database knowledge. Because of this implicit EF dependency it may as well contain a context itself.